# first fundamental form: an example with $r_x=(1,0,f_x)$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces

I cannot find the procedure on how, in Example I in the  second snippet below,
$$r_x=(1,0,f_x)$$ is found.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ of the map

$$(x,y) \mapsto (x,y, f(x,y)).$$

Comment: Right. Yet, how is derived $dl^2$ on the second line in the second snippet from $l$ as in the **Lemma 3.3.** ?

Comment: @user122424 that is a different question. .. that deserves a different post.

Comment: [Done](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4496905/first-fundamental-form-how-can-i-derive-it-from-the-length-l-int-sqrtg-ij).

Comment: @ChristophermarkLee I have understand it myself. If I need a further help, i'll repost it!

Answer (score 1):

$r$, the position vector, is always $(x,y,z)$, that is, $r=(x,y,z)$.

On this surface $z=f(x,y)$. So we can parametrize the surface by $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

Hence, on the surface, $r=(x,y,f(x,y))$.

So, $r_x=(1,0,f_x)$.